# VB.Net : Creating Multiple Balloontips Notification with NotifyIcon Control

Tags: vb.net

I'm currently developing a simple program for my company to approve and acknowledge request, using Visual Studio NotifyIcon to help showing notification via BalloonTip. However, I'm unable to show 2 BalloonTips in the same time, but instead the latter notification overwrites the first BalloonTip.

Is there a way to show multiple BalloonTips without the old one being overwritten?

I'm using Visual Studio 2010 with .Net Framework 4.0 to develop the program.

Thank you before.

Best Regard,

Jeff

Comment: One `NotifyIcon` can only show one tool tip at a time.  You'll need to find some other way to provide notifications, e.g. toast or multiple icons.

Comment: Thanks for the respond @jmcilhinney. I have found a workaround with the current tool tip.